# Get the percent of time elapsed between two javascript dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, date, time

I'm trying to find how many days are left in a school year and return it as a jQuery UI progressbar.

jQuery UI progressbars only take percentages.  How can I find the percentage of how far along I am in the timespan between two supplied dates, given today's date?

Answer (score 9):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FLaJM/4/

```
var start = new Date(2005,0,1),
    end = new Date(2021,0,1),
    today = new Date();

alert( Math.round(100-((end - start) * 100 ) / today) + '%' );
```

or if you wanted the percentage remaining:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FLaJM/3/

```
alert( Math.round(((end - start) * 100 ) / today) + '%' );
```

Comment: I needed the inverse: someDate = start.getTime() + ((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) * percentage).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/), which I highly recommend for Javascript date stuff, you could do this:

```
var percentOfDayRangeComplete = function(start, end) {
    var now = moment();
    start = start || moment(now).startOf('day');
    end = end || moment(now).endOf('day');
    var totalMillisInRange = end.valueOf() - start.valueOf();
    var elapsedMillis = now.valueOf() - start.valueOf();
    // This will bound the number to 0 and 100
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(100, 100 * (elapsedMillis / totalMillisInRange)));
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60eyyk58/) to see it in action...

Answer (score 1):

```
completed = ((timenow - timestart) / (timeclose - timestart)) * 100
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer worked for me, thanks. Simple and vanilla js is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (algorithmically - you can figure out the code as an exercise) is to:

1. Determine the number of days you have in the school year (typically ~185 for most public schools)
2. Calculate the number of school days left between your current date and the end of classes (make sure you ignore weekends, holidays, in-service days, etc as these are not part of the 185).
3. Take the value from step two and divide it into the first. That will give you your percentage.
4. Display that in the jQuery UI progress bar.