# Calculate percentage between two dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to calculate the percentage between two dates given the code from some questions here in StackOverflow but the code doesn't work correctly.
This is the question: [Get the percent of time elapsed between two javascript dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672652/percent-of-time-elapsed-between-two-dates)

```
var start = new Date(2015,6,1),
end = new Date(2015,12,1),
today = new Date();

alert(Math.round(( ( today - start ) / ( end - start ) ) * 100) + "%");
```

I want to calculate the progress from the 1rst of june to the 1rst of december and I get "-7"

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Percent of what, exactly?

Comment: You can get the difference between the 2 dates easily enough, but then what do you want to see that as a percentage of?

Comment: He wants to see how far the current date is in on the time interval. The code seems to work fine if you use different years.

Comment: What do you mean the code doesn't work, you didn't even implement it correctly. [It gives 1%](http://jsfiddle.net/FLaJM/197/). Be more clear on what you mean by "progress" between dates.

Comment: @RayToal Yes the OP already mentioned that in the question... If you are meaning to reply to my comment then I'm saying that it gives 1% with the code the user mentioned in the link that apparently doesn't work (and please use *@username*). Basically the user isn't clear on what output they want and why the code in the link is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript counts months from 0 to 11. January is 0 and December is 11. You specified June to December, but entered 6 and 12.

Answer (score 8):

```
 var start = new Date(2015,6,1),
 end = new Date(2015,11,1),
 today = new Date();

 //use Math.abs to avoid sign
 var q = Math.abs(today-start);
 var d = Math.abs(end-start);
 alert("Rounded: "+Math.round((q/d)*100) + "%");
 alert("Fraction: "+((q/d)*100) + "%");
```

Also read Ray Toal answer 6 is july not jun

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that month number 6 is July, not June, so your answer is coming out negative.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using momentJs

```js
var startOfDate =  moment("2015.6.1"),
endDate =  moment("2025.12.1"),
todayDate =  moment();

 const daysDifference = moment(endDate).diff(startOfDate, 'days');
 const difference = todayDate.diff(startOfDate, 'days');
 
 const result = Math.round((difference / daysDifference) * 100);
 alert(result)
 console.log({result})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: For those of you wondering... here is a link to moment docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
var start = new Date(2015,6,1),
end = new Date(2015,12,1),
today = new Date();

alert( Math.round(((end - start) * 100 ) / today) + '%' );
```

Comment: I've already mentioned this in the comments, using the code from the answer the OP links to and claims is wrong, gives 1%. Although we are not sure if that's what they want.